# How do I change a group policy setting via cmd?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, gpedit

I often have to put together PCs to get shipped elsewhere, usually from an image, then do some final installs that vary. I have a few settings I end up setting in gpedit.msc, and sometimes installing software or updates causes them to get reset.

I'd like to write a .bat or .psh that would allow me to set the settings I want rather than clicking through the menus.

I downloaded LGPO.exe from Microsoft, but it does not seem to let me directly change things, seems to be about backing up and restoring the whole thing.

What if I want to just set
Configuration -> Administrative -> Templates -> Windows Components ->Autoplay Policies -> Turn Off Autoplay On

To enabled, or some other similar thing? There should be some way to do that from command line right?

Comment: Strictly speaking you don’t change the group policy you change the registry key.  Why do you want to do this with a command prompt instead of PowerShelll?

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't change the registry key.  The group policy, not stored in the registry, is applied to registry keys at system start, logon, and every two hours. It is in a pol file. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/policy/registry-policy-file-format. For the specific function the user has asked for this is **also** a user setting. See https://www.howtogeek.com/236241/how-to-enable-disable-and-customize-autoplay-in-windows-10/. and is in this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers`.

Comment: I am okay with power shell, I just want to write a script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The "Turn Off Autoplay" policy option can be enabled or disabled
via the registry.
It is very strongly recommended to leave it as disabled,
as it is known to be used by viruses.

In Windows 10, total disable/enable of AutoPlay is via the registry
at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers
DisableAutoplay - REG_DWORD
Value:1 = AutoPlay disabled
Value:0 = AutoPlay enabled
```

It can be more finely set in the registry by two keys in
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_CURRENT_USER, meaning in either
the Computer Configuration and User Configuration folders.
If the policy settings conflict, the policy setting in
Computer Configuration takes precedence over the one in
User Configuration.

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

The `NoDriveTypeAutoRun` item is of type REG_SZ and is composed of
the following bits as required:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 0x1 | Disables Autoplay on drives of unknown type. |
| 0x4 | Disables Autoplay on removable drives. |
| 0x8 | Disables Autoplay on fixed drives. |
| 0x10 | Disables Autoplay on network drives. |
| 0x20 | Disables Autoplay on CD-ROM drives. |
| 0x40 | Disables Autoplay on RAM disks. |
| 0x80 | Disables Autoplay on drives of unknown type. |
| 0xFF | Disables Autoplay on all types of drives. |

Microsoft counsels against enabling AutoPlay, so the rules may
change from one Windows version to the next, but always in the
direction of making it harder to use.

Reboot is required after any registry change of these items.

Comment: Thanks, but I just picked that one as an example, does every Grouppolicy match to a registry entry? And will the setting stick the same as if I set in gpedit.msc?

Comment: Almost all policies are expressed as registry entries, but also not all of them are known. If you can't find it on the internet, you can always try using [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace the `gpedit.msc` to find out what it does.